# How to simply get GridView's SelectedIndex value of a certain cell

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

The thing is this: I have a GridView control which is populated with data from an SQL table. Each column has simple data such as strings or int numbers. My last column is a "Select CommandField", which pops up a form when clicked. I am trying to make a function in JavaScript which needs to use the value of the first column of the selected row; how is the syntax for this?

Like in C# it would be

`myGridView.Rows[myGridView.SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text`

so in JavaScript it should be something like

`var grid = document.getElementById('myGridView');
var gridRow = grid.rows[<what_Should_I_Type_Here?>].cells[0].text`

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Possible? yes definitely. Possible without learning the basics of javascript and html? definitely not.

Comment: So is this too far from the basics?

Comment: this is totally basics. jquery is almost a must and once you know how the selector works its piece of cake

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = document.getElementById('myGridView'); 
var gridRow = grid.rows[document.getElementById("myGridView").selectedIndex].cells[0].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Redirect(row) {
                var rowData = row.parentNode.parentNode;
                var rowIndex = rowData.rowIndex;
                var grid = document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_Grd_Dashboard');
                var value = grid.rows[rowIndex].cells[0].innerText;
                alert(value);
                window.location = "PoTracking.aspx?Pid=" + value;
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Try this ..This is get index value and redirect to another page